# Generate an output file with python inside a php script

Tags: php, python, bash, shell, exec

I need help in figuring out on how to generate an output file in python inside php script.

So here is the problem:
I have a php script that lets user upload files.
Those files are stored in the server.
After that those files will be run on a python script, and will generate output files.
After that the php script will get those output files, and send an email to the user.
I want to make it automatically send to the user after they upload and click the submit button.

I have all those done, until trying to call a python script inside the php script
The python script inside the php script does not execute the function where it generates the output files.

This is the function that I use for calling the bash script:

```
system('bash /data/home/rxs061/public_html/test.sh');
```

I also have used the function exec(); and shell_exec();
But does not work.
The problem here, the function does not run on the command line, so the output file won't be generated.

This is inside the bash script (test.sh):
`python /home/rxs061/public_html/test.py
outfile=$PWD/test.out
echo "$PWD/"`

The problem here it does not want to generate "test.out"

This is inside the the python script (test.py):
`import sys
outfile = open('test.out', 'w')
outfile.write('it worked\n')
outfile.close()`

This does not have to do with permissions.
How do you put this all together in a single php script?
Or are there any other solutions?
Or how to make it output files???

Comment: `test.sh` is not a Python script, it's a bash script (which itself runs a Python script).

Comment: why dont u send the email in python? make everything async

Comment: More importantly: what is `$PWD` when you run `test.sh`? What were you hoping for it to be?

Comment: Finally, what do you mean by "does not work"? What does "does not run on the server/unix shell" mean? What actually happens?

Comment: @abarnert $PWD is the path. So If I run the exec('bash /data/home/rxs061/public_html/test.sh') or shell_exec("bash /data/home/rxs061/public_html/test.sh") or system("bash /data/home/rxs061/public_html/test.sh"), the intended output file that is inside the test.sh, that is test.out won't be generated. Because it only can be generated when I ran "bash /data/home/rxs061/public_html/test.sh" in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I get all fix, it something to do with the permission.
After I do chmod 777, it is all fixed