# Running python script inside PHP (add to Pandas df and save file)

Tags: python, php, pandas, bash, shell

When a user chooses an xlsx file and submits through POST, I would like to get that file, put it in a pandas df, do some data cleansing/formatting, and then send it back to the browser as a downloadable csv.

I've got the python/pandas script working.
I've been able to successfully pass a simple $PHP variable (file name) to the Python script, print that out in Python, and then echo that back out in PHP.
...but I can't get the rest of my Python script to run (pandas portion). It's as though the rest of my script doesn't exist.

What I'm doing is:

1. Move temporary submitted file from $_FILES to another folder (same directory) called 'uploads'.
2. Grab the path of the newly saved file.
3. Pass that into Python script and save formatted file to uploads/completed-- **I assume here is where I've failed somewhere**

(I'm not figuring out the part on how to send the file back to the browser yet-- just trying to get the file in first).

I have a python venv installed in my htdocs folder and it is activated.

My PHP:

```
$fname = $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
$upload_path = 'uploads/' . $fname;

$output = shell_exec('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/venv/bin/python3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/data_cleanse.py ' . $upload_path);
echo $output;
```

My Python that works:

```
import sys
print("Variable passed to Python is: " + sys.argv[1])
```

My Python that won't do anything (works when I sub sys.argv[1] with a regular file name):

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

uploaded_file = sys.argv[1]

df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)
df.to_csv('uploads/completed/completed_doc.csv')
```

I am not yet trying to print the df to PHP. I am just trying to see if I can generate the csv file.

I've tried escapeshellcmd and system which did not work. I read a [really similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167678/generate-an-output-file-with-python-inside-a-php-script) which mentioned chmod 777 for setting permissions. I did that to change permissions and now my folder is readable & writable by everyone but it still won't run.

I'm confused because it all seems to run fine and connect fine except for the pandas portion. Can someone please help? I am new to PHP and would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you’re close.
The hick is that PHP is processed server-side, so if you want your POST to return the webpage code, send back HTML, as PHP is used to generate HTML server-side.

If you have a PHP engine on your server, you can save the PHP server-side, and return a public link to the newly minted PHP page in the POST response.

Comment: Hope this helps you get on the track you’re looking for!

Comment: Oops, I pressed 'enter' too early. Is your answer addressing the returning csv to the webpage part?

Where I am getting stuck is that my Python file does not seem to run (for parts that don't respond to PHP). PHP passes the variable to my Python file and echos it back correctly... but the part of my python file that creates a CSV never seems to run (no CSV file appears in my 'completed' folder). Thanks again.

Comment: I guess my confusion is that sys.argv[1] correctly holds the filepath and can be echoed back onto the webpage (working with PHP)...  so I am confused why df.read_excel(sys.argv[1]) seems to do nothing!

Comment: What makes you say the read is failing, and not the write?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure... I've been able to successfully run my python script when manually typing in the file path. It specifically fails when I put sys.argv[1] as the variable to the file name and try to trigger the python script by submitting a file through POST. And I'm not getting any error message.

Comment: Ok... I have no idea what happened but it suddenly started working!! Thank you for taking a second to advise on my question - I will use that tip when returning output to the webpage!! :)